# C exiting a program correctly

Tags: c

Hello I am writing a c program which runs then waits for it to complete then executes an if condition. However after the child process completes it does not execute the rest of code in parent. Any advice would be great. Thanks

AA

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>    
int main() {

    int D, waitVal3, waitVal4;
            D = fork();
        if(D == 0)
        {
            execv("DD", 0);
        }
            if(D != 0)
        {
            printf("\nPid = %d Code AA: created proccess Pid = %d (code DD)\n", getpid(), D);
        }


            waitVal3 = (waitVal4);
           //NEVER ENTERS THIS CONDITION
        printf("WAIT VAL: %d", waitVal3);
            if(waitVal3 == D)
            {
                printf("\nPid = %d Code AA: process Pid = %d terminated\n", getpid(), D);

            }
        return 0;

}
```

DD

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main (int argc, char *argBB[]) {

    int C3, waitVal, waitVal2, ps;
    C3 = fork(); 

    if(C3 != 0)
    {
        printf("\nPid = %d Code DD: created proccess Pid = %d (code CC)\n", getpid(), C3);
    }
    if( C3 == 0 )
    {
        execv("CC", 0);
        printf("\nexecv failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if(C3 < 0)
    {
        printf("Fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    ps = fork();
    if(ps != 0)
    {
        printf("\nPid = %d Code DD: created proccess Pid = %d (code ps)\n", getpid(), ps);
    }

    if( ps == 0 )
    {
        char command[50];
        strcpy(command, "ps -u username");
        system(command);    
        exit(11);
        kill(ps, SIGKILL);//KILL PROCCESS PS HERE
    }

    waitVal = wait(waitVal2);

    if(waitVal == ps)
        {
        printf("\nPid= %d Code DD: process Pid = %d terminated\n", getpid(), ps);
            printf("\nPid = %d Code DD: killing process Pid = %d\n", getpid(), C3);
            kill(C3, SIGKILL);
            printf("\nPid= %d Code DD: process Pid = %d terminated\n", getpid(), C3);
        printf("\nPid = %d Code DD: terminating\n", getpid());

        exit(7);
        }

    return 0;



}
```

Comment: AA does not successfully compile on Ubuntu Linux 16.04... Additionally what is this code in AA:  ` waitVal3 = (waitVal4);`

Comment: Sorry I accidentally removed their initialization when I pasted my code. The purpose of those values is waitVal3 should be the process Id of DD. After the wait function is complete it should enter the if condition below but it does not.

Comment: Where do you call "wait()"  in AA ..???

Comment: well....this is embarrassing. You deserve a big fat green check. Provide an answer with that comment ill give you credit. THANKS!!!

Comment: From the top code block, need to check if fork() failed.   if ( D == -1 ){ ... }. Also need to check if execv() failed.  if( execv() == -1 ){ ... }

Comment: What is the executable 'CC'  supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call wait() and your execv() was incorrect... 
... compare this with your version to check the differences...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>    
#include <string.h>    
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {

    char *args[2] = {"DD", NULL};
    int D, waitVal3, waitVal4, rc, waitStatus;
    D = fork();
    if ( D == -1 )
    {
        printf("fork failed\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    if(D == 0)
    {
    // ORIG: execv("DD", args);
    rc = execv("/some/path/to/DD", args);
    printf("execv failed: errno: %d\n", errno);
    exit(1);
    }
    if(D != 0)
    {
    printf("\nPid = %d Code AA: created proccess Pid = %d (code DD)\n", getpid(), D);
    }


    waitVal4 = wait(&waitStatus);
    waitVal3 = (waitVal4);
       //ORIGINALLY - NEVER ENTERS THIS CONDITION
    printf("WAIT VAL: %d", waitVal3);
    if(waitVal3 == D)
    {
    printf("\nPid = %d Code AA: process Pid = %d terminated\n", getpid(), D);

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Don't you need to check the returned value of rc to determine if it failed? Like "if (rc == -1 ){  ... failed ...  }

Comment: @Nguaial If execv() succeeds, then AA will be "replaced" with "DD"... The printf() following it will only be called if execv() fails...

Comment: I tried with waitpid().  It didn't work.  I posted the code below.  I cannot understand why this won't work.

Comment: The same reason that that I didn't need to check the returned value from the execv() that you asked about in your prior comment... Think of the process of the execv() in this manner... if the execv() succeeds, the program ("AA") stops existing, and DD replaces it in memory...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  When execv() succeeds in A, it looks like it loses the program control. It doesn't follow the concept of returning from a function.  DD goes to LaLaLand after it terminates. Once DD is done, the program flow does not go back to AA.  The only way to synchronize this is with wait() or waitpid().  AA executable is still running and the wait() or waitpid() brings the control back to AA.

Comment: You need to think about it in this manner:  Fork creates a "twin" process, which (with a few exceptions) has only two differences, the newly created twin has a different PID, and the return from `fork()` is a zero (whereas in the original "twin" (i.e. the "original" forking process) fork() returns the NEW TWIN's pid).  Now there are TWO processes, each with its own control flow, and both at the same point in the code.  The NEW twin calls `execv()` and it STOPs being a TWIN... it is now DD.... when DD exits, its exit status is available to its "parent" (i.e. original twin) when wait() is called

Answer (score 1):

I tried to come up with a solution using waitpid() instead of wait().
Why this didn't work?

```
int main() {

char *args[2] = {"DD", NULL};
int  waitVal3, waitVal4, rc, waitStatus;
pid_t D;

D = fork();
if ( D == -1 )
{
    printf("fork failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

if(D == 0)
{
   // ORIG: execv("DD", args);
  if( execv("/home/ubuntu/workspace/C/DD", args) == -1 ){
      printf("execv failed: errno: %d\n", errno);
      exit(1);
  }
  if( waitpid( D, &waitStatus, 0 ) == -1 ){
      printf("Error waiting child process.\n");
      exit(1);
  };
  printf("\nPid = %d Code AA: process Pid = %d terminated\n", getpid(), D);
}

return 0;
}
```

Observation:
  If I put the waitid() statement outside the child process, this works.
  The following code worked:

```
if(D == 0)
{
   // ORIG: execv("DD", args);
   if( execv("/home/ubuntu/workspace/C/DD", args) == -1 ){
      printf("execv failed: errno: %d\n", errno);
      exit(1);
   }
}

 if( waitpid( D, &waitStatus, 0 ) == -1 ){
    printf("Error waiting child process.\n");
    exit(1);
 };

 printf("\nPid = %d Code AA: process Pid = %d terminated\n", getpid(), D);
```

This means that the parent process was able detect the termination of child process in this case.  My understanding is that waitpid() should work whether
in child or parent process.  I am firm believer that it did work.  However, the consequent printf() statement in the child process didn't get executed since the child process got terminated.